# Any good sources to demonstrate Heisenberg uncertainty principle using polarizers?

Tags: linear-optics

Sakurai introduces QM using Stern Gerlach experiment. He also demonstrates HUP using the experiment.

SG experiment deals with spin. However, spin is very similar to polarization. Hence, HUP should also be demonstrable using polarizers.

Are there any good sources which deals with it ?

Comment: What is “it” in “it should also be demonstrable using polarizers”? Are you asking if *spin* had a relation to polarization?  Otherwise, the Heisenberg uncertainty principle would be manifest in the uncertainty of horizontal/vertical polarization of a photon having 45 degree polarization, for example.

Comment: it means Heisenberg Uncertainty principle. HUP is manifested by incompatible observables. So if we take 3 polarizer experiment using a vertical, 45, and horizontal polarizer, keeping vertical first and replacing the position of H and 45 in first step and second, we will see that the observation changes for both steps. This shows that the 45 and H polarizations are incompatible. Similar to Sx and Sz being incompatible observables. Their commutator will not be zero.

Comment: I found a paper along similar lines. http://static1.squarespace.com/static/56b6357e01dbaea0266fe701/t/56c433792b8dde24de99e52a/1455698810284/Sofia-Svensson-Testing-Heisenbergs-Uncertainty-Principle-with-Polarized-Single-Photons.pdf

Comment: This answer on physics stackexchange also discusses it, https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/240546/28922